# How can I get a text from a window?

Tags: python, windows

Here my function:

```
def getEditText(hwnd):
    result = []
    bufferlength = struct.pack('i', 255)
    linecount = win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.EM_GETLINECOUNT, 0, 0)
    print"--- linecount :",linecount

    for line in range(linecount):
        linetext = bufferlength + "".ljust(253)        
        linelength = win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.EM_GETLINE, line, linetext)
 myLigne=linetext[:linelength] 
 print"  ",myLigne
        result.append(myLigne)
    return result
resultat=getEditText(hwmdTexte)
```

I want to get the text from a widget but this doesn't work. 
There are several lines in the widget of my application but I have linecount=0 and of course no text...
Could you please help me.

Comment: 1. Formatting seems broken. 2. What widget, with what GUI toolkit, etc. ?

Comment: First of all, verify that your `hwnd` refers to an edit control (and not to a window containing edit control, etc). Use Spy++ or similar tool to confirm your assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also think there's a problem with the control. However, I've checked it with 2 different tools (WinID and AutoIt). The name of the control is TEXTE. Moreover I've tried a for loop, just in case.                                          for handle,nom,classe in controls:
       resultat=GetTex(handle)                                There's another thing I don't understand: why with WinID and AutoIt I can get the text of some aplication but not with this one...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I've just tried                          def

```
GetText(hwnd):
    buf_size = 1 + win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0)
    buffer = win32gui.PyMakeBuffer(buf_size)
    win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_GETTEXT, buf_size, buffer)
    return buffer[:buf_size]
```

But this doesn't get the text of my widget. This function returns NUL...